# spring boot - calculated field

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

So, I have an entity, that has field start_date (java.util.Date is the type).

I want to have another field, that would automatically populate with integer that corresponds to day of week (as a number 1 for sunday, 2 for monday, etc.) of starting date.

Here's fragment of my entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date start_date;
```

I've tried to add the calculated field in the following way:

```
@Column(name = "weekday")
@Formula("(select dayofweek(l.start_date) from Lesson l where l.id = id)")
private Integer weekDay;
```

However, when looking at the Lesson table in H2 console, there's no such column as "weekday"

I also tried other option - without @Formula annotation and with a setter that takes start_date parameter, but I guess this setter is never called, since the column "weekday" is populated with null.
Here's the setter I've tried to use as an alternative solution:

```
    public void setWeekDay(Date start_date) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(start_date);
    this.weekDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
}
```

It's obvious that I'm missing something here, it's probably because I'm still learning Spring boot...

To sum up - I want to have a column in table Lesson, that is calculated from another column of the same table.

Comment: One other thing to note, is that the time package is a much more complete and better system to use than the java.util.Date or sql.Date which are both broken in a variety of ways.  You should consider switching to it or JodaTime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@Formula` means your field to be calculated by your rules. This entity field is not column in db. This field is calculating for each entity in loading time by specified rule.

If annotation `@Column(name = "weekday")` would work near `@Formula` you would be really confused if you expect in loaded entity same value as in DB but here is calculated one and different (inconsistent situation).

If you want save here value from the `Lesson` table you should remove `@Formula` and use `@EntityListeners({YourEntityJpaCallbacksListener.class})` In spring bean `YourEntityJpaCallbacksListener` you can define methods marked with `@PreUpdate` or `@PrePersist` and use correspond operations to set calculated value into `weekday`.

for example:

```
@EntityListeners({YourEntityJpaCallbacksListener.class})
@Entity
public class YourEntity{
    // your code
}

@Component
public class YourEntityJpaCallbacksListener {
    @Autowired
    private LessonRepository lessonRepository;

    @PreUpdate
    void preUpdate(YourEntity yourEntity) {
        if (recurrentRuleRepository.exists(yourEntity.getId())) {
            Integer weekDay = lessonRepository.findOne(yourEntity.getId());
            yourEntity.setWeekDay(weekDay);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are right, I actually(finally) managed to solve this without using @Formula at all. I have created a method that writes the data to weekDay and I'm calling it from start_date setter, so everytime start_date is created or update this method is called.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your solution seems much more elegant

Comment: nice to here. Any way you already solved it and I think it makes better your experience.

Comment: do not forget accept this answer, if it was helpful for you.

Comment: I have tried the setup above with no success.  The `@Autowire` annotation on `LessonRepository` does nothing for me because the entity listener used when persisting the entity is not created by Spring.  (The field is always null.)  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I think I have managed to solve this.

I have removed the @Formula annotation
I have created a method that calculates the day of the week and writes it to weekDay.

```
public void calculateDayOfWeek(){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(start_date);
    this.weekDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
}
```

And I put it inside start_date setter:

```
public void setStart_date(Date start_date) {

    this.start_date = start_date;
    calculateDayOfWeek();
}
```

So now, evertime the start_date is created or updated, it updates (or creates) the value of weekDay.