# How to retrieve a calculated value using Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is my current implementation

```
@Query(value = "SELECT NEW, ID, NAME, MASS_OUTPUT, TEMPERATURE, WATER_OUTPUT, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_USER, MODIFIED_DATE, MODIFIED_USER, PRESSURE_PROFILE_ID, PRESSURE_PROFILE_PRESET_ID,RECIPE_ID,USER_ID FROM \r\n" + 
            "(\r\n" + 
            "(SELECT 1 as Rank, true as NEW, ID, NAME, MASS_OUTPUT, TEMPERATURE, WATER_OUTPUT, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_USER, MODIFIED_DATE, MODIFIED_USER, PRESSURE_PROFILE_ID, PRESSURE_PROFILE_PRESET_ID \r\n" + 
            "FROM RECIPE \r\n" + 
            "where CREATED_DATE > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)\r\n" + 
            "UNION ALL\r\n" + 
            "(SELECT 2 as Rank, false as NEW, ID, NAME, MASS_OUTPUT, TEMPERATURE, WATER_OUTPUT, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_USER, MODIFIED_DATE, MODIFIED_USER, PRESSURE_PROFILE_ID, PRESSURE_PROFILE_PRESET_ID \r\n" + 
            "FROM RECIPE \r\n" + 
            "where CREATED_DATE < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)\r\n" + 
            ") \r\n" + 
            "AS A JOIN USER_RECIPE AS B ON ID=RECIPE_ID where B.USER_ID= ?1", 
countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USER_RECIPE WHERE USER_ID = ?1",
nativeQuery = true)
List<UserRecipe> getAllUserRecipesWithPagination(String userId, Pageable sortedByField);
```

Ignore the long query. With this query, I'm trying to retrieve the newest element first(Records younger than 1 day)

"NEW" is not an attribute in the UserRecipe Entity. I'm going to use NEW to identify the newest elements.

I'm hoping to user @Transient do this, but cannot find the proper way to do this. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use @Formula  in this case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323231/spring-boot-calculated-field and example https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/hibernate/formula-in-hibernate-example.html

Comment: I will able to resolve my issue with this @Eklavya. Thanks.